# How To Add an SWF To Blogger?

Tags: flash, blogger, blogspot

I've created an Air swf with Flash and uploaded it to Google Sites but it didn't work with Blogger. Then I converted the Air file to Flash format and the same thing.

They work fine with Comodo Dragon and Tor Browser but the swf can't be displayed with Firefox, Google Chrome and IE.

Here's my code:

```
<embed align="middle" allowscriptaccess="always" height="450" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" quality="high" src="http://sites.google.com/site/onurcan1977/test.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="450"></embed>
```

Here's my page: http://cangunay55.blogspot.com/2014/03/test.html

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox!!!

Comment: Path to your file redirects. give proper path of file.